# Count occurrences of given words per each list in a tuple of lists

Tags: python, list, count, append

I have a list of tokenized sentences and I want to count the collective occurrence of several words:
e.g.:

```
example_list = (['hey', 'there', 'you', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
                ['i', 'am', 'fine', 'how', 'about', you],
                ['i', 'am', 'good'])
```

Now I want to count how many times the following words occur in each list and append the score in a list

```
score = []
test = ['hey', 'you']
```

I try the following code:

```
for i in range(len(test)):
   for j in range(len(example_list)):
       score1.append(example_list[j].count(test[i]))
```

and get the output of:

```
[1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0]
```

whereas I want an output of:

```
[3, 1, 0]
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) inside a list comprehension:

```
example_list = (['hey', 'there', 'you', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
                ['i', 'am', 'fine', 'how', 'about', 'you'],
                ['i', 'am', 'good'])



test = ['hey', 'you']


score = [sum(s in test for s in lst) for lst in example_list]
print(score)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 1, 0]
```

Consider using a set if `test` is large enough.

Comment: Do you also have a smart way to compute the nested length of each list? i.e how many words in that list?

Comment: @apol96 `[len(lst) for lst in example_list]`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Counter` for this task:

```
from collections import Counter


counters = [Counter(l) for l in example_list]
occurrences = [sum([c[word] for word in test if word in c]) for c in counters]

print(occurrences) # [3, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested list comprehension with `sum` to add the occurrences of all elements in `test`.

Also, you might want to build a `set` from `test` for a faster lookup:

```
test = set(['hey', 'you'])

[sum(s in test for s in l) for l in example_list]
# [3, 1, 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a traditional `for` loop:

```
example_list = (['hey', 'there', 'you', 'how', 'are', 'you'],
                ['i', 'am', 'fine', 'how', 'about', 'you'],
                ['i', 'am', 'good'])
test = ['hey', 'you']
score = []

for lst in example_list:
    total = 0
    for word in test:
        total += lst.count(word)
    score.append(total)

print(score)
```

Output:

```
[3, 1, 0]
```